# Pass parameter from Liquid to JS function

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, liquid

I have the next code

```
{%- if my_page.title -%}
<a class="page-link" onclick="return smoothlyScrollToSection()">{{ my_page.title | escape }}</a>
{%- endif -%}
```

`smoothlyScrollToSection` defined before in code. It works fine.

I want to pass `my_page.title` as a parameter to `smoothlyScrollToSection`. Is there a way to do it?

```
<a class="page-link" 
   onclick="return smoothlyScrollToSection({{my_page.title}})">
{{ my_page.title | escape }}</a>
```

Doesn't work

Comment: `{{ page.title }}` is certainly what your looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the single quotes...

```
<a class="page-link" 
onclick="return smoothlyScrollToSection('{{my_page.title}}')">
  {{ my_page.title | escape }}
</a>
```

It is a string and you should let Javascript know.